# CSS with Option tag - Editing text color

Tags: html, css, html-select

Is there any secret behind editing a option tag with css? I just can't solve this issue

```
<option> FirstName <span class = "foo">SecondName</span> </option>

.foo{
    color:#666666;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The secret is that you can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`<option>` elements cannot contain anything other than text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/option). So no, you can't apply a style to a section of their content.

Just don't use a `<select>`, or don't bother about styling. From your use case, it doesn't really look suitable anyway. It'd be better just to type the name, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it is better. This was more of a theoretical question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but there are some new developments in the world of CSS!

`color` property on `select` will now set color of option(s) text (including selected), while adding / over-riding color to `select option`.

**CSS:**

```
select {
  color: white; /* color of selected option */
 }

select option {
  color: black; /* color of other options */
}
```