# Can't override CSS font color for <select> <option> for a single character

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS with Option tag - Editing text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717796/css-with-option-tag-editing-text-color)

I know I must be overlooking something very simple. I am trying to change the color of the asterik (*) next to the SELECT AN AMOUNT  just showing customer that it is required. I have tried span and font tags specifying the color but nothing seems to work. I can't seem to override the css for the select. Any help is appreciated.

I have posted code here also: http://jsfiddle.net/RGFAc/

```
<style type="text/css">
.styled-select select {background: transparent;width: 150px;color:#333333;font:bold 11px Arial, sans-serif;border: 1px solid #ABADB3;height: 25px;}
</style>

<div class="styled-select">
<select name="id" id="id">
<option value="">SELECT AN AMOUNT <span style="color:#EE3124">*</span></option>
<option value="gift5">$5</option>
<option value="gift10">$10</option>
<option value="gift15">$15</option>
</select></div>
```

Comment: Some browsers let you manipulate `option` elements, others don't. It's unreliable, so if you have to have it, use a `select` dropdown replacement.

Comment: @JaredFarrish ... and lose semantics and - alas - confuse screen reader users (except if they use a very recent one and the replacement uses correctly ARIA), just for one asterisk.

Comment: For now I'll just have to do a pre-check before form submit and alert the user if they forgot to select that option. I even tried placing the asterik outside, next to the '/option' and it won't even display there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can't style text inside the options tag.

Similar question: [CSS with Option tag - Editing text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717796/css-with-option-tag-editing-text-color)

Answer (score 0):

You're styling the `select`, but the `option` element itself has a `span` inside it with its own color. Have you tried overriding that directly?

```
.styled-select select#id option span {color: #333 !important;}
```

Comment: Yes, I can't get anything to change it. The span that is in the code was the last thing I tried. I am trying to change the asterik color to #EE3124 everything else I want #333333.